# Unable to import images: InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided is not a valid name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm very new to React Native, and I'm trying to import an image into my app but I keep gettin this error:

> InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/static/media/logo.ab75c327.png') is not a valid name.

This is my code right now:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, Image} from 'react-native';

import style from './styles';
import Logo from '../../../assets/images/logo.png';

export default () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Logo />
        </View>
    );
}
```

It should be something super simple, but for some reason it isn't working for me.
I also tried using `<Image source={Logo} />` as well, but still doesn't work.

I then decided not to import the Logo and tried `<Image source='../../../assets/images/logo.png' />`.
When I do this, I no longer get any errors, but the image simply doesn't show up.

I have tried with other images and other formats as well, and in all cases I end up getting the same results.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the image using the `<img>` tag, like:

```
<img src={Logo} alt='logo'/>
```

Your code corrected:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, Image} from 'react-native';

import style from './styles';
import Logo from '../../../assets/images/logo.png';

export default () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <img src={Logo} alt='logo'/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a react programmer but I see the javascript import statement is for modules, not images locations. That might have something to do with it and gels with your errors.

See mozilla javascript docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) for more info on the javascript import syntax.

Cheers.

Comment: In react you can import css and images from location, the example code is correct